# Onclick Syntax using RadGrid ItemTemplate

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, telerik-grid

I always get a yellow screen of death what's the correct syntax for this part?

```
OnClick="GMap(\''+<%# String.Format("{0} - {1}",
         Eval("Latitude"), Eval("Longitude")) %> + '\')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("GMap(\"{0}\", \"{1}\");",  Eval("Latitude"), Eval("Longitude")) %>'
```